# can't access .mov file on apache http server

Tags: linux, http

I have an apache http server running on my CentOS machine. I created a simple index.html in /var/www/html folder along with some video files. The index.html contains links to each video files. The http server was working fine until I added a .mov file. Every time I tried to access that .mov file, I got permission denied error. I have use "chmod 755" on that .mov file. This .mov file is much larger than other files. I don't know why it is behaving like this. Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have that MIME-type set on your server?

Comment: no. In my httpd.conf, I can see a line like this: "TypesConfig /etc/mime.types". Then I go to /etc/mime.types and I see these lines:" video/quicktime    qt mov". Does that mean .mov file is supposed to be supported?

Comment: This might be a typo in your paste, but it should look like:  `AddType video/quicktime .qt .mov`

Comment: I can find some "AddType" statements in httpd.conf but not in /etc/mime.types. Should I add "AddType video/quicktime .qt .mov" to httpd.conf? But it seems that TypesConfig /etc/mime.types does the job.

Comment: I just tried to add "AddType video/quicktime .qt .mov" to httpd.conf. it doesn't work.

Comment: It's probably right in your setup.  Can you verify what user is access the file?  And try chmod 777

Comment: figure it out. It is the Linux security context of my .mov file get changed. I have to set it to httpd_sys_content_t. I don't know why that happens, but it is working now. Thanks for the help.